# Multipart File(more than one file) Upload Using Spring Rest Template + Spring Web MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am unable to send a multiple files using Rest template. How can I send a multiple file in single REST template call and on receiver(host) side what is the controller method?

The code below code is working for sending a single file.

### Client side code

```
LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
map.add("file", new ClassPathResource(file));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = 
    new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> result = template.get().exchange(
    contextPath.get() + path, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
    String.class);
```

### Host controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
@ResponseBody
public String readFiles( MultipartFile file){
    ---
    ---
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF8"));

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Arrays.asList(new LoggingRequestInterceptor()));

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        String uri = "https://if-one.pl/api/v1/documents";

        String imagePath = "/path_to_file/do1.jpg";
        String imagePath2 = "/path_to_file/do2.jpg";

        MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        map.add("doctype", "idcard");

        Resource file1 = new FileSystemResource(imagePath);
        Resource file2 = new FileSystemResource(imagePath2);

        map.add("file", file1);
        map.add("file", file1);
        HttpHeaders imageHeaders = createHeaders();
        imageHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> imageEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, imageHeaders);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(imageHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<String> resposne =
                restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, imageEntity, String.class);
```